# What does נלבעה mean?

Tags: hebrew, cemetery-grave, acronyms

When written on a tombstone, what does נלבעה mean (e.g. נלבעה יום שישי)?

Also, more importantly, which is more correct: נלבעה or נלבע"ה? Is the quotation mark necessary to indicate proper meaning (i.e. because it's an acronym)?

Furthermore, should it be: נלבעה ביום שישי? Or, is shishi just fine?

Thanks very much for your help and advice.

Answer (score 5):

It means נלקחה לבית עולמה which means “taken to her eternal home”.

Most abbreviations have the quote marks before the last letter (e.g. שליט"א ביהמ"ק) so נלבע"ה seems better.

נלבע"ה ביום שישי means "taken to her eternal home on Friday". This obviously needs more date information.

Comment: Thanks very much Avrohom! ... We're actually working on correcting an old tombstone. So if we should add the quotes("), it's good to know as well. In reality, she passed on Friday night, so it should say Shabbat. However, we're not sure if they have the room to fit in "Shabbat Kodesh". Would נלבע"ה שבת קודש be correct? Or does it have to be נלבע"ה יום שבת קודש? Either case, which is more accurate? (Of course this sentence continues with the date, year, etc.) Thanks again!

Comment: I was told that the "נ" stands for נפטר/ה

Comment: @Larry I don't recall seeing tombstones with the day of the week specified (since that doesn't bear much significance as regards one's Yahrzeit). The (Hebrew and, sometimes, English) calendar date is the only date I've seen specified. For example, נלבע"ה א' חשון התשס"ה.

Comment: @Lee, thanks! I think the authors wanted to mention the day because it was on Shabbat. If we do mention Shabbat, should it be יום שבת קודש, or would just יום שבת okay?

Comment: IMHO (נלבע"ה א' חשון התשס"ה (שבת

Comment: Don't forget, "Like any library, Mi Yodeya offers tons of great information, but does not offer personalized, professional advice, and does not take the place of seeking such advice from your rabbi.". If this is a real question, ask your (or a) local orthodox Rabbi.